# How to find _any_ formula error in a Google Sheet via a standard command (and not a script)?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

For complex Google Sheets with many tabs (my teams effectively employ Google Sheets as a sort of database in these scenarios), is there a relatively-easy way to search for *any and all* formula errors (across all tabs) [like these errors](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/formula-parse-error/) without having to create a script?

I'm thinking something like a `Find and replace` option that offers a `Find formula errors` checkbox.

The purpose: when adjusting formulas, named ranges, and the like: it's quite cumbersome for a spreadsheet designer/maintainer to manually look through all formulas in all tabs to find if anything is broken. We'd rather employ some automated-find-any-errors mechanism to avoid such efforts.

I've performed non-trivial web searches and searched all the features I could find within Google Sheets, and I see nothing like this feature. The only other option I see is writing a significant, embedded script or other automation, which is what we're looking to specifically avoid.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: I spent roughly 20 mins web searching and all I found was references to `iserror()` and `iferror()`-like questions and answers. I found ZERO reference to _any_ functionality like I describe above.  @Rubén - does this background meet the mark/requirements?

Comment: You could also mention what you have tried so far (add all of this to the question, by the way, have you already look at the Google Sheets menus, functions list and help articles?).

Comment: @Rubén - I appreciate you're applying SE policies here. However: I've been posting tech question for decades. I believe I've supplied sufficient background for all your points for anyone who has any appropriate experience with Google Sheets or Microsoft Excel. Let's leave it be. If there's a real problem, then let's point it out. Otherwise, I feel adding more background then I've already done (which imo is significant) makes the question unnecessarily long - which per my decades of experience dissuades people from reading the question. Regardless: I sincerely appreciate your efforts.

Comment: I just made a suggestion, no downvote, no close vote. It is up to you to take the suggestion or not. Any way, have you already tried to use find and replace to search for #N/A, #VALUE!, etc.? How about using adding an auxiiary sheet togehter with IFERROR, IFNA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Sheets doesn't include that as a built-in feature. Please send a feature request direclty to Google through the Google Sheets Help menu

> At this time the menu shows "Help Sheets to improve".

It's worthy to mention that FIND AND REPLACE can highlight / navigate through the cells diplaying an error, i.e. `#N/A`

[image]

You could even use regular expressions to search for multiple errors.

Comment: Super helpful, thanks @Rubén !